# Using Postgres "copy" command in Talend to load table content into CSV file

Tags: postgresql, copy, talend

I have to copy few postgres table contents into a CSV file for further processing using Talend.

When I tried

```
copy table_name to ‘/tmp/export/table_name.csv’ with CSV;
```

with 'tpostgresqlRow' component, it threw error saying "Need superuser access", which I wouldn't be getting.

As an alternative, I tried "\copy" command as

```
\\copy table_name to ‘/tmp/export/table_name.csv’ with CSV;"
```

(first slash is used to escape the other). Still it threw error saying "Syntax error at '\'".

I tried with tpostgresqlBulkExec component as well, which internally uses "copy" command, and it as well threw error saying "Need superuser access".

Is there a way out to execute this postgres "copy" command in bulk using Talend?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got confirmation from Talend Support Team that tPostgresqlRow component would not support 'COPY' command. I have resolved my case by installing PSQL client and calling the same using tSSH component in Talend to execute the desired 'COPY' commands.

Comment: Can you give details on how you have done it and provide a link, please. I am new to Talend and have no idea what PSQL client, tSSH you've installed and where?

Answer (score 0):

The copy command needs access to both the postgres table and the local file system.

I think your problem is caused because you do not have access to the local folder. you need to sort that out, or try a different folder that you know you have access to.

with the same user, if you try linux command

```
touch /tmp/export/test.csv
```

you may see an error.

the \copy command will fail because to use that you first need to be using a tool called psql.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I am able to touch /tmp/export/test.csv. The file system is taken care. So, the psql needs to be installed on cloud or remote engine wherever I am running my Talend job and use tSystem to invoke \copy command through command line?